# Landau-Siegel zeros: Why can't they be found?

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Let me situate myself in this discussion: I'm not a mathematician or someone who had a comprehensive mathematical training. Yet I do have a great interest in Mathematics and I've been recently reading about the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis and the zeros of the zeta function $\zeta (s)$. I also learnt about the Landau-Siegel zeros which, as I understood, are real (non-complex) zeros of $\zeta(s)$  very close to $s = 1$ (to the left). The zeta function is well defined, continuous and differentiable (or isn't it?) in the west neighbourhood of $s = 1$. With the computers we have today and with the bunch of numerical methods known, finding a root should not be an unsurmountable task for an applied mathematician, or so I believe. How come no one has ever found one of these roots yet? Right, they may not exist, but their non-existence is a consequence of not finding them. I know numerical methods have their limitations and are no substitute to a formal proof, but can't they be explored somehow? Or *are* they being explored $-$ it's just me who am unaware of those endeavours?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes indeed, but I'm optimistic and working with the hypothesis that someone can do it very well. ;-)

Comment: I am confused : Aren't the real roots (named as "trivial roots") of the zeta function $-2,-4,-6,\cdots$ ? How can they be near $1$ ? Are those roots from another function ?

Comment: @Peter A Landau-Siegel root is a potential counterexample to GRH, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel_zero). It would be near to $s=1$.

Comment: Carlos, all numerical computations have shown that there is no such Landau-Siegel root. But clearly this is no proof that they don't exist.

Comment: So there could be a real root of the zeta function near $1$ ? Or is this (possible) root from another similar function ?

Comment: It is from a Dirichlet function $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}$, a generalisation of $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: @Peter It is hypothesized that besides the known real roots you mentioned other real roots may exist in a narrow region in the neighbourhood of _s_ = 1. AFAIK mathematicians have made successful efforts to make this region even narrower. However these roots (or even a single root) haven't been found yet.

Comment: Maybe , I misunderstood Dietrich's comment but it sounds like this root would not come from the usual zeta function , but from a generalization. Of course , those generalizations might have such a root. I wonder whether the "usual" zeta-function could have such a root. I never heard of this reading the wikipedia article about the zeta-function. Therefore I am confused.

Comment: @DietrichBurde You seem to be aware of numerical efforts attempting to find Siegel zeros. You would appreciate if you could cite one. I'm really interested in giving a look to what has been done in this field.

Comment: There are many results, e.g., see [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022314X2300094X).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks, I will give it a look.

Answer (score 2):

Landau-Siegel zeros do not refer to zeros of $\zeta(s)$, but instead to (potential) zeros of Dirichlet $L$-functions associated to quadratic Dirichlet characters. Specifically, if $\chi$ is a real quadratic character mod $D$, then the question is to determine if there are zeros within approximately $1/\log(D)$ of $s = 1$ in the Dirichlet $L$-function
$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}.$$
People have computed an enormous number of zeros for an enormous number of quadratic Dirichlet $L$-functions. It is possible (and not even particularly challenging) to show that there are no zeros with real $s$, $\frac{1}{2} < s < 1$, for any individual Dirichlet $L$-function. But the challenge is that there are infinitely many Dirichlet $L$-functions, and we can't check them all one by one.